# Java 1.7 allows integer values with '_', why not while parsing Integer

Tags: java

e.g.

```
String myString = "10_000";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(myString));
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "10_000"

Comment: do you think `_` is a number ?

Comment: We can't answer "why" questions as we are not the language designers. We may offer educated guesses. My opinion is that this is to prevent existing code from breaking. That is, code that expects numbers to only contain digits and expects an exception to be thrown when anything else is there.

Comment: Changing this would come at a high risk: existing applications might break, acceptung input that used to be rejected prior to the change and so even cause security issues when running on newer versions of Java. But what would be the benefit of this change? I don't see anything worthwhile in allowing this.

Comment: ... and the question is?

Answer (score 3):

Because the spacers were introduced to provide clarity for the programmer, so he can write `1_000_000`, but that's not the same as parsing a number.

The spacers are for source code (and programmer eyes) only.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing '_' to be parsed in parseInt would go against the explicit documentation of the method.

parseInt

Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: Bear in mind that Java 7 is past its End-of-Life.

Answer (score 0):

Java *does* allow you to use `_` to specify a number literal:

```
int a = 1_000_000;
```

This is mainly to make the code easier to read.

But Java can't spot number literals in a string, right? It just treats everything inside `""` as a whole string literal. Also, `parseInt` is written in such a way that it only accept numbers without the separator marks.

To parse a string like `"1_000_000"`, you can first remove the `_`s, then parse it:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(myString.replace("_", "")));
```

Comment: "To parse a string like" Nearly. I mean, yes, that is how you can parse strings with underscores, ignoring the underscores; but it's not the same as what's acceptable in source code: it accepts strings like `___1`.

Comment: Those aren't strings the compiler accepts, they're numeric literals. If they were strings​ they'd be wrapped in quote marks `"`.